# Retrieving info from a table on a website?

Tags: browser, website

I am not a very technical person but I would like to ask if it is possible to retrieve the contents of a table on a website?

This table is spread over 400 pages, I use it regularly when working but the problem is that my internet is unstable and often does not work, so I cant access the table which prevents me from being able to work.

Is there a way i can download/copy it so that I can use it when my internet is down?

The website: http://www.hok-cba.hr/default.aspx?sec=20 > "Odvjetnici" & "Odvjetnicki urdedi i drustva".

PS: When i attempt to save the website I can not view the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's actually quite easy. You need a program called scraper - such as Outwit Hub (paid) or service-based: http://import.io (free) 
check their tutorials: 
http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/topics/41446-the-data-browser- 
 and especially 
http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/247564-create-an-extractor

Comment: BTW Import.io just announced AutoExtract feature just for tables:  http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/315618-auto-table-extraction